# How can I enable/disable submit-buttons dinamically when its textarea is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I've the following HTML pages:

HTML 1

```
<div class="row">    
    @foreach($postList as $post)
        @include('Pages.Post.postInGroup', ['post'=>$post, 'commentsList'=>$commentsList])
    @endforeach
</div>
```

HTML 2

```
<form id="msform" action="{{route('comments.store')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row align-items-center">   
        <!-- nascondere bottoni per visitatori -->
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="{{url(Auth::user()->picture_path)}}" style="border-radius: 50%;" width="30" height="30" alt="User Picture">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-9" style="display: inline-block;">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" > <!--style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 1px;"-->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" style="background-color: #228B22;"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$post->id}}" name="postId" id="postId">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, `HTML 1` can repeat the `HTML 2` code a number of times based on the number of objects in `$postList`.
`HTML 2` contains an image, followed by a `textarea` and a `submit button`.

What I want to do is `disable` the submit button only if its corresponding textarea is empty.

For example, I have cycled 3 times, so I'll have:

1. Textarea - Button
2. Textarea - Button
3. Textarea - Button

If I wanted to write in the 2nd textarea, then I will have to `enable` only the button adjacent to that textarea. I hope my problem is clear.

**Warning**, I cannot change the name of the textarea, cause I use it inside a controller to get the data from the textarea like this: `$comment_content = $request->input('comment_content');` and I want to disable/enable only the submit buttons that I've posted in `HTML 2`.

**EDIT**

NEW HTML 2

```
<form id="msform" action="{{route('comments.store')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row align-items-center">   
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="{{url(Auth::user()->picture_path)}}" style="border-radius: 50%;" width="30" height="30" alt="User Picture">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-9" style="display: inline-block;">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" id="comment_content {{$post->id}}" name="comment_content" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" >
            <input type="submit" name="comment_button {{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" style="background-color: #228B22;"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$post->id}}" name="postId" id="postId">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$theGroup->id}}" name="groupId" id="groupId">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, each time a `@foreach` cycle is executed, the textarea `id` will be `comment_content {{$post->id}}` and the `name` of the submit button will be `comment_button {{$post->id}}`to guarantee the dynamism of the elements, as requested in the question. So now, if I repeat the cycle three times, I will have:

1. Textarea(id="comment_content 1") - Button (name="comment_button 1")
2. Textarea(id="comment_content 2") - Button (name="comment_button 2")
3. Textarea(id="comment_content 3") - Button (name="comment_button 3")

Comment: Do you mean if the text area is empty the button next to it will be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to keyup, so when the user is typing if the value is empty that will disable/enable the submit button

```js
//start with them disabled
$('#msform > div > div > input[name=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

//while user is typing disable and enable based on the value.
$('#msform > div textarea').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).parents('.row').find('input[name=submit]').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="msform">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <!-- nascondere bottoni per visitatori -->
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="border-radius: 50%;" width="30" height="30" alt="User Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-9" style="display: inline-block;">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
      <!--style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 1px;"-->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" style="background-color: #228B22;" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="postId" id="postId1">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <!-- nascondere bottoni per visitatori -->
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="border-radius: 50%;" width="30" height="30" alt="User Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-9" style="display: inline-block;">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
      <!--style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 1px;"-->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" style="background-color: #228B22;" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="postId" id="postId2">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <!-- nascondere bottoni per visitatori -->
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="border-radius: 50%;" width="30" height="30" alt="User Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-9" style="display: inline-block;">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
      <!--style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 1px;"-->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" style="background-color: #228B22;" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="postId" id="postId3">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You understood the idea of what I meant to do, but unfortunately, with a foreach loop, it doesn't work like that. I tested your script but it doesn't work as you showed in the snippet, so we need to improve your solution.

Comment: To help you with the changes, as I said, I cannot change the `name` field of the textarea for data extraction reasons, but I can try to alter my code by changing the id and verifying that my application continues to work. I will try to add an id field also to the submit button, so that you can recognize the `submit button` and the `textarea` not from the `name` field but from the `id` field.

Comment: I am not using the name of the textarea anywhere in my code. not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**About disabled buttons**

Disabled buttons can be harmful for the user. Let the button always be enabled, and show inline validation messages if required fields are empty when the user press submit.

More information: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76301/form-validation-and-disabled-buttons

**Native form validation**

You can use native HTML5 validation to get this behavior. Look at this simplified example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvGLrm

```
<form>
  <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

More about native form validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: The disabled buttons, if well managed, are not harmful and don't cause problems, for example Facebook: if you don't write something in the textarea, the "Post" button will not be enabled.